# Loopback Model Object JSON

Tags: node.js, json, loopbackjs

I'm currently using LoopbackJS 3. I'm trying to define my model JSON properties for a model called Answers. I don't understand how can handle array of object.

```
    Model.defineProperty('answers', {
        type: [{
            type: {
                type: {
                    type: String,
                    default: "text",
                    required: true
                },
                message : {
                    type: String,
                    required: true
                }
            },
            type: {
                type: {
                    type: String,
                    default: "image",
                    required: true
                },
                path : {
                    type: String,
                    required: true
                }
            }         
        }],
        required : false
    });
```

I expect to see something like this:

```
"answers": [
    {
      "type": "text",
      "message": "string"
    },
    {
      "type": "image",
      "path": "string"
    }
  ]
```

But actually loopback show me just:

```
"answers": [
    {
      "type": "image",
      "path": "string"
    }
  ]
```

Comment: check out the official document here [link](https://loopback.io/doc/en/lb3/LoopBack-types.html#array-types)

Answer (score 0):

That's expected. 
The objects you defined has the key "type" twice.

[image: screenshot]

Objects can't have twice the same key, only the last one is kept.
I would advise using loopback-cli for generating models.

I'm not sure you can define an array with two different types.
All examples using arrays define one type

```
['string'] 
[{type: 'string', required: true}]
```

I think you have two simple options:

1. define a model Element

   > elementType: "string" (you can enfore before save elementType === "text" or "image"
   >   value: string
2. Use theses relations

   > Element belongsTo Thread
   >   Thread hasMany Element

```js
const thread = new Thread(...)
thread.answers = [
   {type: "text", value: "..."},
   {type: "image", value: "..."}
]
```

I hope this helps!